# Java KeyPress arrow keys triggers numpad keys

Tags: java, keyevent

When using `Robot.keyPress` for the KeyEvent `VK_UP`, the numpad key is triggered rather than the normal arrow key.
I am trying to write a keyboard emulator that can be used for games etc. Testing with TrackMania I notice that it does not trigger the normal key, but the key on the numpad.

How can I trigger the normal keys using keyPress?

Checking the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_UP), it is supposed to be the non-numpad arrow key. Which it isnt.

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
```

This will generate the numpad up key.

If this cannot be done in Java, is there any language that allows it?

Comment: Did you try to get the value of the up key handling the keypressed event and pressing the up key?

Comment: They way my system works is that it records, from a KeyListener, a key press from a user into a KeyEvent, which is later used when passing a value to keyPress. So the same value (the non-numpad key press) is used as a trigger.

Comment: You probably had the *Num Lock* Key on when you recorded your data. Normally there is no problem distinguishing between numpad and normal keys.

Comment: There is no difference if I have _Num Lock_ enabled or disabled. Same result.

Comment: I ran into this problem awhile ago.  It appears impossible to trigger the non-numpad keys with Robot. I remember there was some bug report about this, but I can't find it.  Which version of Java did you use?

Comment: Right now I can't remember which exact version of Java I was running, but I am sure it was pre-Java 7 (some version of 6 basically).

Comment: did you implements key event listener? If not, you should do