# Java awt Robot still cant press non-numpad arrows on windows?

Tags: java, awt, keypress, awtrobot, arrow-keys

This bug is known for years, yet is is still present in Java `1.7.0_25` version which I'm using on Windows 8. The following result are same regardless of wether i have numlock turned on or not:

```
Robot bot = new Robot();

bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP); //this in documentation is non-numpad up arrow key
bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP); //pressed the numpad up arrow key

//folowing line is line #43
bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP); //this in documentation is numpad up arrow key
bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP); //causes folowing exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code
at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.keyPress(Native Method)
at java.awt.Robot.keyPress(Robot.java:358)
at test.RobotArrow.main(RobotArrow.java:43)
```

I know this question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565510/java-keypress-arrow-keys-triggers-numpad-keys) but over a year ago, so is there any progress? I cant google anything, there is even an [ofiicial bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4760074)

So, is there finnaly a solution or not?

Answer (score 0):

//PRESS WINDOWS + ARROW LEFT

```
Robot divideWindow = new Robot();
divideWindow.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
divideWindow.delay(100);
divideWindow.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
divideWindow.delay(100);
divideWindow.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
divideWindow.delay(100);
divideWindow.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
```

Works fine for me :)

Comment: I'm testing this with empty JFrame and capturing event with KeyboardFocusManager and this doesn't do what I want. I want to press a non-numpad arrow key via Robot, this presses windows + arrow key, thusly moving my JFrame accordinly, i dont want that.

Comment: This is not a substitute for pressing the arrow keys; it will activate Windows shortcuts to move windows.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to disable numlock. See [this jdk bug comment](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7015209?focusedCommentId=12125457&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12125457)